# PHP session variable not persisting while others are

Tags: php, kohana-3

Using Kohana 3 in a windows environment. I am able to get some session variables to pass through to other pages however one variable in particular does not get persisted.

setting

```
Session::instance()->set('user_id', $this->_post['username']);
Session::instance()->set('user_pwd', $this->_post['password']);
Session::instance()->set('session_state', $tmp);
```

Getting

```
  $this->_uid= Session::instance()->get('user_id');
  $this->_pwd=  Session::instance()->get('user_pwd');
  $this->_session_state= Session::instance()->get('session_state');
```

For some reason `Session::instance()->get('session_state')` contains nothing. Whenever I print out the array for sessoin:instance. Is there something with the characters I am passing through?

example of this session variable.

> `$tmp = 2.000000015f92d17e669733b522ba1afdee23205b44a6f19731dbb759a09d5a81bf18338cdb789b4b317dfe38a5fddaa81cb4c153dbbfc672b5fa5b8f8d1071e340134d46bc46fff3965db1d62b64be5195d8b603f350eb28a9cba087efc1dfbb99f8aad5bcd5dd75b21807b52c9c95ce3840fdf7263ff08c643a0c56477503f751ceb2cd1b88401f.1033.0.1.America/New*_York.wps*_1*_prun*_1.00000001618cb83feb74e6dd9d51a073f6841f859b9b04a5d30c4acd8672594d87b2d30e956cc482e999d1e6c2858f36564bbc4184718dd7bf663cf21299e9565caf.00000001c39a4f9dcf4dfaa07a2cbfa2e76f82e0c911585a51ebb8d4ff783513ebdec801e539ef70.0.1.1.MicroStrategy Tutorial.B19DEDCC11D4E0EFC000EB9495D0F44F.0-1033.0.1_-1033.0.1_-1033.1.1_1.1.0.*0.Not+specified.6.e`

There are some special characters preventing this, after I use `htmlspecialchars()` the value is passed successfully through.

Comment: Have you tried it with just a simple string like "test"

Comment: What does $tmp contain?  Can you post an example?

Comment: Yes simple strings will work, this is also proven by the other session variables passing through correctly.

Comment: and how about the name? Can you save your `$tmp` variable to a session with a different name?

Comment: It seems to be some character in the variable. Whenever I wrap tmp with htmlspecialchars() the value is passed through. But I need to know what it changed.

Comment: How is your view controller? Are you using any templating modules? Which Kohana 3 version is this? Which adapter are you using? (Native, Cookie or Database?) Do you have the encrypt set to True?